# Visual Studio Code functional snippet React

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

Does anybody knows what's the shortcut for React functional components snippet in Visual Studio?
I have the ES7 React/Redux/GraphQL/React-Native snippets extension enabled in the editor.

Answer (score 34):

If you wish to create `React functional component` snippet in `VS Code` follow these steps.

1. Go to `File - Preferences - Configure User Snippets`
2. Dropdown will appear. Select `New Global Snippets file` and type `<any-name>` you want and hit enter
3. File should be created with the following name `<any-name>.code-snippet`
4. Paste this code. Anything you type in `prefix` will be your component trigger

```
{
  "React Functional Component": {
    "prefix": "rfc",
    "body": [
      "import React from \"react\"",
      "",
      "const ${1:name} = (props) => {",
      "  return (",
      "    <div>",
      "      $2",
      "    </div>",
      "  )",
      "};",
      "",
      "export default ${1:name};",
      ""
    ],
    "description": "React Functional Component"
  }
}
```

5. Save the file
6. Type (in this case) `rfc` and hit enter.

Comment: It may be worth adding a scope line, `"scope": "javascript, typescript"

Comment: in latest versions of react, its not necessary to import react. But just mentioning, understand that the main motive is to show how to make a snippet.

Answer (score 22):

I used the `rafce` live template for new components.

This creates code like:

```js
import React from 'react';

const MyComponent = () => {
    return (
        <div>
        
        </div>
    );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Answer (score 7):

I found the solution for my problem (tnx to Krzysztof Podmokły). I would like to share some improved code particularly for component in React (it fills name of the file instead of just name, and I deleted import React, as long as it doesn't needed anymore).

```
    {
      "React Functional Component": {
        "prefix": ["rfc"],
        "body": [
          "",
          "const $TM_FILENAME_BASE = () => {",
          "  return (",
          "    <div>",
          "      $2",
          "    </div>",
          "  )",
          "};",
          "",
          "export default $TM_FILENAME_BASE",
          ""
        ],
        "description": "React Functional Component"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to generate function component snippet, use below key

Function component -> rnsf

Const component -> tsnf

VS code

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

`sfc` is used with 'Simple React Snippets' extension to create statless functional components. The generated template is :

```
const ... = () => {
 return (  );
}

export default ...;
```

Answer (score 2):

Intstall this extension (is required for creating these components)
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dsznajder.es7-react-js-snippets

Then you can create file, ex: MyComponent.jsx (or .tsx)
Type in `rafce` (VS Code will suggest you some of these) and hit Enter

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer of @Niko, that provides the useful `${TM_FILENAME_BASE}` placeholder, here is a snippet for Typescript functional component that, besides naming the component after the file, adds the interface for props as **ComponentNameProps**:

```
"React Functional Component": {
    "prefix": "rfc",
    "body": [
      "import React from 'react'",
      "",
      "export interface ${TM_FILENAME_BASE}Props {",
      "}",
      "export function $TM_FILENAME_BASE  ({}:${TM_FILENAME_BASE}Props)  {",
      "  return <></>",
      "};"
    ],
    "description": "React Functional Component"
  }
```

and, assuming that the file is named `FileName.tsx`, creates this:

```js
import React from 'react'

export interface FileNameProps {
}
export function FileName  ({}:FileNameProps)  {
  return <></>
};
```